# What does this engraving on Stormbreaker’s mould mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I was recently re-watching *Avengers: Infinity War* and I noticed that there are some sort of engraved circles on the Stormbreaker’s mould. Here’s a screenshot:

[image: Stormbreaker's mould sits on a moving track; it is sort of H-shaped with a circle/ring pattern in the centre of it]

At first thought, it looked very similar to the Bifrost landing markings.

Is there an official/confirmed indication that the engravings on the mould **are** in fact Bifrost markings?

Comment: At a guess, the rings refer to the Nine Realms of Norse mythology.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any specific meaning to the mould's markings that I can find. We can rule out the most common suggestions though. It's not the same as the Bifrost markings as they are more detailed patterns and runic:

[image: Thor stands in the centre of the Bifrost markings holding Mjolnir and looking up off of the desert floor]

They also don't appear to be representative of the Nine realms. There are 8 lines in each quarter making 7 overlapping pairs. An argument could be made that the circle off the end is one of the Realms and then each line is represented of another but this doesn't appear to be the case.

I actually think they don't have a meaning but rather a *purpose*. Note how the lines move from the outside and snake their way to the centre hole of the mould. Where the lines start as well we see that the mould angles slightly downwards into the hole. These appear to actually be guiding lines to urge the metal into the hole as well as somewhat stylistic.

[image: The molten Uru pours from one mould into the centre of another, off to the right hand side we see the process being duplicated.]

You can actually see it a bit easier in *Marvel's Avengers: Infinity War - The Art of the Movie* where the angle downwards is more pronouned.

[image: 3D diagram of the mould moving system loaded full of moulds with Eitri almost as tall of it and Thor shown not even reaching the first level; we then see an annotated drawing of the mould labelling the carrier handle for how it attaches to the tracks, the 2 pc bracket and release mechanism for how the carrier attaches to the mould and then the moulds sandwiched together saying "Different shapes and sizes"]

---

Of note is that in the concept art, from the above book, the mould didn't always have this pattern. In the drawing below it has more of a rectangular grid and quite detailed pattern covering the whole outside of it.

[image: Two concept art drawings of the mould' one shows the view over Groot's shoulder looking down at Rocket next to the mould which is laying in a pile of ash and the other shows the pile of ash covering the mould with Eitri's legs next to it; a bright white light shines under both piles]